# My JCheckBox program only displays one box. Why is that?

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

I am attempting to add another checkbox to this program but for some reason it will not display when I run the program. Only the check box for the blue pill displays. I have attempted to add a couple things or change the way the program is structured, but nothing I have done so far has helped.

Code Below:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class CMIS242WK4DonnersonAReply {
    
    static JCheckBox red;
    static JCheckBox blue;
    static JButton button;
    
 
    public CMIS242WK4DonnersonAReply() {
        
        
        button = new JButton("submit"); // Creates submit button 
    widget
        ButtonHandler listener = new ButtonHandler(); // Creates the handler for the button.
        button.addActionListener((ActionListener) listener); // adds the handler to the button widget
        
        
        JPanel content = new JPanel(); // "container"
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);// places submit button at the bottom of panel.
        
        
        JLabel label = new JLabel("At last. Welcome, Neo. As you no doubt have guessed, I am Morpheus.  This is your last chance. After this there is no turning back."); // Label in frame.
        content.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);// places label at the top of the screen.

        //Creating Check Boxes
        JCheckBox red = new JCheckBox("You take the red pill, you stay in Wonderland and I show you how deep the rabbit hole goes.");
        red.setBounds(100,100, 50,50);  
        content.add(red);
        
        JCheckBox blue = new JCheckBox("You take the blue pill, the story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe. ");
        blue.setBounds(100,100, 50,50);  
        content.add(blue);
        
        //Adding Frame
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Matrix Monologue"); // JFrame = Window
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setSize(750,200); // Length, Height
        window.setLocation(200,200); // X/Y "OF THE ENTIRE FRAME" Not the contents
        window.setVisible(true); // makes window visible
       

    }
    
    // Method handles what happens when button is pressed.
    private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed1(ActionEvent e) {
            
            
            // Checks if which pill was selected and responds to user depending on their action.
            if (red.isSelected() == true) {
                System.out.println("Follow me");
                System.out.println();
            }
            if (blue.isSelected() == true) {
                System.out.println("Very Well, You may go back to your world");
                System.out.println();
            }
            else
                System.out.println("You must make a choice for what pill you will take");
            System.exit(0); //closes program
            
            
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            
        }
    }
    
    
    // Main/driver method that runs everything.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CMIS242WK4DonnersonAReply matrixMonologue= new CMIS242WK4DonnersonAReply();
        
    }
}
```

Any pointers?

Comment: In your code you have: `red.setBounds(100,100, 50,50);` and you also have: `blue.setBounds(100,100, 50,50);` You gave them both the same bounds. Is that on purpose? In any case, the bounds are ignored since you are using `BorderLayout`.

Comment: 1) Don't use static variables for your components. That is not what static is used for. 2) Don't use setBounds(). It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location of the component.

Comment: @Abra Well spotted. I think OP skipped the region for checkboxes because maybe he thought absolute positioning took precedence? OP, probably good advice to avoid `setBounds()` no matter what. Let the layout manager you choose do the work for you, because absolute positioning might look good on one device or OS, but look terrible on another. And what if your user resizes the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that you need some guidance with your *Swing* programming. I have rewritten your `CMIS242WK4DonnersonAReply` class. Code is below. But first some comments about the code in your question.

```java
JCheckBox red = new JCheckBox("You take the red pill, you stay in Wonderland and I show you how deep the rabbit hole goes.");
```

You have created a local variable which is [hiding](https://dzone.com/articles/variable-shadowing-and-hiding-in-java) the class member. Hence `static JCheckBox red;` remains null and consequently the following `if` statement will throw `NullPointerException`.

```java
if (red.isSelected() == true) {
```

By the way, the `== true` is not necessary. The following is sufficient.

```java
if (red.isSelected()) {
```

Now another point.

```java
red.setBounds(100,100, 50,50);
```

Since you are using a [layout manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), namely `BorderLayout`, method `setBounds` will be ignored. The layout manager determines where to place the component on the screen.

```java
window.setContentPane(content);
```

By default, the content pane of [JFrame](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) is a `JPanel` with `BorderLayout` so no need to replace the default content pane.

```java
private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener
```

No need to create a nested class. Simply make class `CMIS242WK4DonnersonAReply` implement the [ActionListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) interface.

```java
System.out.println("Follow me");
```

I don't think it's a good idea to involve the console in a GUI application. I would use [JOptionPane](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) to display a message to the user.

```java
static JCheckBox blue;
```

I think that [JRadioButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) is more appropriate than `JCheckBox` in your situation.

Here is my code.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class CMIS242WK4DonnersonAReply implements Runnable, ActionListener {
    private JButton  button;
    private JRadioButton  blue;
    private JRadioButton  red;
    private JFrame  window;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        if (red.isSelected()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Follow me.");
        }
        else if (blue.isSelected()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "Very Well, You may go back to your world");
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(window, "You must make a choice for what pill you will take");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
    }

    private void createAndShowGui() {
        window = new JFrame("Matrix Monologue");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JLabel label = new JLabel("At last. Welcome, Neo. As you no doubt have guessed, I am Morpheus. This is your last chance. After this there is no turning back."); // Label in frame.
        window.add(label, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        window.add(createCheckBoxes(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        button = new JButton("submit");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(button);
        window.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        window.setSize(750,200); // Length, Height
        window.setLocation(200,200); // X/Y "OF THE ENTIRE FRAME" Not the contents
        window.setVisible(true); // makes window visible
    }

    private JPanel createCheckBoxes() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        red = new JRadioButton("You take the red pill, you stay in Wonderland and I show you how deep the rabbit hole goes.");
        blue = new JRadioButton("You take the blue pill, the story ends, you wake up in your bed and believe whatever you want to believe.");
        ButtonGroup grp = new ButtonGroup();
        grp.add(red);
        grp.add(blue);
        panel.add(red);
        panel.add(blue);
        return panel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new CMIS242WK4DonnersonAReply());
    }
}
```

Here is how the app looks when I run it.

[image: screen capture of running app]

Answer (score 5):

When you're stuck on a problem, it never hurts to go back and consult the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html).

You'll find information like this:

> A border layout lays out a container, arranging and resizing its
> components to fit in five regions: north, south, east, west, and
> center. Each region may contain no more than one component, and is
> identified by a corresponding constant: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, and
> CENTER. When adding a component to a container with a border layout,
> use one of these five constants...

When you add your button, you do this:

```
content.add(button, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

But then, when it's time to add checkboxes, you do this:

```
content.add(red);
        
...

content.add(blue);
```

Are you seeing what's missing? My bet is that you only see the blue checkbox because you added it on top of (or simply displaced) the red checkbox. Remember, the doc says "Each region may contain no more than one component..."

Try specifying the region of your BorderLayout where you want to see each checkbox.

If you want them to appear in the same region, put them in a JPanel of their own and lay them out at NORTH and SOUTH or EAST and WEST and then add that checkbox panel to your `content` panel in the region you want them to appear.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly but I attempted to change the bounds and now I can see the box, but only when I hover over it. Also it is now in a odd region

Comment: I have fixed the problem but I noticed when I click the submit button nothing happens.